# Couldn't import pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have already installed pandas for using it in python but when I write the code to import pandas, it couldn't be used. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What happens when you try `import sys` and then `sys.__file__` in each case? If those results are different, it means that different *installations* of Python are being used, even if they are the same *version*. You must have Pandas - or any other third-party library - installed *for the Python that is in use*. That includes virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDLE and Command Prompt might use different python binaries.

There are two options you can try:

1. To make sure you're using the same python binary that has pandas installed, launch IDLE using `python -m idlelib` from command prompt
2. If you want to use IDLE from start menu that could use a different python binary, run this on IDLE Shell to make sure you have pandas there

```py
import sys,subprocess
subprocess.run(sys.executable + ' -m pip install -U pip', shell=True, capture_output=True)
subprocess.run(sys.executable + ' -m pip install pandas', shell=True, capture_output=True)
```